# Simple Script that I want to make better

Tags: javascript, html

Hi have a simple script that shows an hides a button at a specific date/time:

```
 <div id = "cunextseason" style = "display:none"> <b>TEXT DISPLAYED TO CUSTOMER WHEN FORM IS NOT DISPLAYED</b></div>
    <div id = "div1" style="display:none"><form xxxx
    </form>

    </div>

    <script type = "text/javascript">

    var today = new Date();

    var startEventDate = new Date ("April 4, 2020 22:00")
    var endEventDate = new Date ("April 4 2020 22:05");
    if ((today >= startEventDate)  && (today <=endEventDate)) {document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "block"}
    else {document.getElementById("cunextseason").style.display = "block"}

    </script>
```

Is there a way that I can make that script use `href="https://www.zeitverschiebung.net/en/city/5419384">` date/time instead of computer date/time?

Thank you for ANY suggestions that I can get.

Comment: Is there a reason you need that specific site? There are [lots of sites](https://www.programmableweb.com/category/time/api) that support a REST API which would be the most convenient method. Maybe you could clarify your purpose.

Comment: Are you looking to use the Denver timezone itself?

Comment: I am looking specifically for Denver Time Zone. I am such a beginner, I am not sure how to implement a solution that uses a REST API. If there is a simple way to implement a REST API - I am all ears :)